# Loop through assigned values in an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Say I have given array

```
int[] array = new int[50];
```

Then, say I assign 5 numbers to 5 locations

```
array[4] = 2
array[12] = 0
array[17] = 5
array[42] = 8
array[49] = 4
```

Is there a way I can loop through just the numbers I assigned without having a list that says "4, 12, 17, 42, 49" and get the output of "2, 0, 5, 8, 4"?

Comment: No. There's no way to distinguish an index where you explicitely stored 0, and an index where 0 is there because it's the default value. Now if the array can only contain a positive number, or -1 to signal an uninitialized value for example, then you can loop through the array and find all the indices where a positive number is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the boxed type Integer which can be null.

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[50];

... assignment ...

for (Integer i : array)
    if (i != null)
        System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Is there a way I can loop through just the numbers I assigned without having a list that says "4, 12, 17, 42, 49" and get the output of "2, 0, 5, 8, 4"?`

No. you cannot do this with arrays. This will break the very purpose of array. You are actually expecting it to behave like a map.

Use proper map for this purpose. Here is an example

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(4, 2);
map.put(12, 0);
for(Integer value : map.values()) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

No, because you have to iterate over the whole array, unless you somehow store what values are set (what you don't want).

Yes, you can achieve to only get the output you want by setting some default values. For example initialize the array with [Integer.MIN_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) and only handle values that are not equal to that value.

Comment: `only handle values that are not equal to that value`. To do this he will have to iterate through all over the array. It is not possible in arrays to get directly the value being set without checking. So it is 100% NO

Comment: That's why I say `No, because you have to iterate over the whole array`.